# Nominal/ordinal Variable Measures of Association

Tags: categorical-data

I have an ordinal variable (employee performance ratings on 5-point scale) and I want to do a crosstab with a nominal variable (4 levels of race/ethnicity).  What is the best measure of association for these two variables in SPSS?

Comment: Could you add more details on your design: How were data collected (sampling scheme), what is the total sample size? Showing us a simple contingency table might help to figure out a good test in your case.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on RSK's second point, another option would be to apply a non-parametric test which would account for the ordinal nature of the performance variable -- this would be a Kruskal-Wallis test ([see Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%E2%80%93Wallis_one-way_analysis_of_variance))
, which is a non-parametric analog to a one-way ANOVA.

(You can do this in SPSS 19 under "Non-parametric tests"/"Independent samples". (performance as the independent variable, so chosen under the "Test Fields" list in SPSS 19, and the race/ethnicity variable in the "Groups" list. -- in older versions of SPSS you select the "K independent samples" option under non-parametric tests.)

It is important to note that:

1) As per most non-parametric tests, you are only looking at the hypothesis testing angle (rather than parameter estimation) and so you don't get succinct summaries like odds ratios;

2) As per one-way ANOVA with more than two groups, because your grouping variable has four levels, the p-value from the test is an omnibus result -- that is, a significant result indicates that at least one of the groups is different from at least one of the other groups. To determine which groups are different, you would then need to run some post-hoc tests (e.g. compare all pairs of groups with a Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon test, which is a non-parametric analog to an independent samples t-test.) If you do this, you may want to consider adjusting the p-values for multiple comparisons (e.g. with a Bonferroni correction) to avoid type I error inflation.

Another option would be to apply ordinal logistic regression to the data analysis: this would give you a very similar (if not identical) p-value about the prinicipal hypothesis, as well as summaries of individual group estimates in the form of odds ratios.

Comment: Could you indicate how a non-parametric test, based on rank of the observations, could account for the ordinal nature of the variable? At best, assuming equal shape for the distributions a non-parametric test allows to test for a difference in location and has nothing to do with a measurement model, right?

Comment: @chl I suppose this is a question for the OP too, dependent on the research question: this proposal is a relatively simple analysis of a relatively simple hypothesis, to see whether one or more groups tend to have higher scores than other groups (difference in location). So (apropos your comment) I'm not sure how this doesn't account for ordinality? But as you say, this analysis gives no information about the shape of the distribution. So this approach could perhaps be considered supplementary to e.g. a cross-tabulation of performance by race/ethnicity.

Comment: @chl Also: in terms of "measurement model" -- presuming that you meant in terms of summarising the relationship(s) with a summary statistic like an odds ratio?

Comment: Re: your last comment; I was thinking of an underlying measurement model of "performance" as a latent trait measured with a Likert-type scale but I may have incorrectly extrapolated the scope of your first sentence on "the ordinal nature of the performance", so no worry.

Comment: @chl No worries -- and it's been a long time since I've thought about latent variables!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about SPSS, but any test on contingency tables (e.g., Fisher's) can help. Alternatively, you can assume that the ordinal variable is numerical and use nonparametric alternatives to ANOVA maybe ...

Comment: "any test on contingency tables" doesn't account for the nature of the response variable (which is ordinal in this case) nor the particular design (Fisher's test assumes that margins are fixed). A trend test might be interesting, depending on the sample size per strata.